# Limit Involving a Tetration of the Variable

Tags: limits

We wish to evaluate this challenging limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x^{x^{x{^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}-1}{x-1}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}}
$$

**My Observation** : As an initial guess, I shall consider $f_{n}(x)=x^{x^{x{^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$ with $n$ being the number of $x$. To simplify this problem I considered the case of $n=1$, it is easy to see that the limit is $1$, to be sure of my assertion I further considered the case for $n=2$, we receive :
$$
\left(\frac{x^{x}-1}{x-1}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}}
$$
We thus simplify this expression :
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{x^{x}-1}{x-1}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}}&=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\ln\left(\frac{\exp(x\ln(x))-1}{x-1}\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\ln\left(\frac{\exp(x(x-1+o(x-1)))-1}{x-1}\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\ln\left(\frac{1+x(x-1)+o(x(x-1))-1}{x-1}\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\ln\left(x+o(x)\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}(x-1+o(x-1))\right) \\
&=\exp(\sqrt{x-1}+o(\sqrt{x-1}))
\end{align*}
Where :$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\exp(\sqrt{x-1}+o(\sqrt{x-1}))=1$$

Now the big question is how can we extend this for the general case that is for $n\geq3$? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_n=\left(\frac{x^{x^{x{^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}-1}{x-1}\right)^{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}}\implies \log(a_n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\log\left(\frac{x^{x^{x{^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}-1}{x-1}\right)$$

Using @Ninad Munshi's answer, we then have that, around $x=1$, for an infinite tetration
$$x^{x^{x{^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}=1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac{3}{2} (x-1)^3+\frac{7}{3} (x-1)^4+O\left((x-1)^5\right)$$ that is to say
$$\frac{x^{x^{x{^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}-1}{x-1}=1+(x-1)+\frac{3}{2} (x-1)^2+\frac{7}{3} (x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$
$$\log\left(\frac{x^{x^{x{^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}-1}{x-1}\right)=(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac{7}{6} (x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$
$$\log(a_n)=(x-1)^{1/2}+(x-1)^{3/2}+\frac{7}{6} (x-1)^{5/2}+O\left((x-1)^{7/2}\right)$$

Now, let us do the same for the discrete cases where $n$ is small
$$\log(a_2)=(x-1)^{1/2}+\frac{1}{6} (x-1)^{5/2}+O\left((x-1)^{7/2}\right)$$
$$\log(a_3)=(x-1)^{1/2}+(x-1)^{3/2}+\frac{1}{6} (x-1)^{5/2}+O\left((x-1)^{7/2}\right)$$
$$\log(a_4)=(x-1)^{1/2}+(x-1)^{3/2}+\frac{7}{6} (x-1)^{5/2}+O\left((x-1)^{7/2}\right)$$

This is a quite fast convergence to order $O\left((x-1)^{7/2}\right)$.

Pushing to $O\left((x-1)^{9/2}\right)$, the coefficient of  $(x-1)^{7/2}$  will succesively be $\left\{-\frac{1}{8},\frac{7}{24},\frac{19}{24},\frac{43}{24}\right\}$ (no $\cdots$).

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}:$ In the limit, the following relationship holds

$$x^{x^{\cdots}} = y \implies x^y = y$$

$$ 1 = yx^{-y} = ye^{-y\log x} $$

which means

$$y = \frac{-W(-\log x)}{\log x}$$

where $W$ is the principal branch of the Lambert-W or product log function (the principal branch is chosen because the limit takes $\log x \to 0$, and the two branches would either make $y$ a $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{0}$ situation). Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Comment** : *I would like to thank Claude and Ninad for your suggestions and answers. I truly believe that this problem needs not the Lambert W function yet I shall accept Claude's answer since he put an effort in helping me with this problem. After spending several hours on this problem I have managed to prove it as follow.*

**My Proof** : For $n\geq3$ we have that :
\begin{align*}
\exp(f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x))\ln(x)&=(1+f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x)+o(\ln(x)))(x-1+o(x-1)) \\
&=x-1+(x-1)f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x)+o((x-1)\ln(x)) \\
\end{align*}
$\implies \exp(\exp(f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x))\ln(x))-1=(x-1+(x-1)f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x))+o((x-1)\ln(x))$

And Since :
\begin{align*}
\exp(\exp(f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x))\ln(x))-1&=\exp\left(x^{f_{n-2}(x)}\ln(x)\right)-1 \\
&=\exp(f_{n-1}(x)\ln(x))-1\\
&=x^{f_{n-1}(x)}-1\\
&=f_{n}(x)-1
\end{align*}
Thus, we have that :
\begin{align*}
\frac{f_{n}(x)-1}{x-1}&=\frac{(x-1+(x-1)f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x))+o((x-1)\ln(x))}{x-1}\\
&=1+f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x)+o(\ln(x))\\
\implies& \ln\left(\frac{f_{n}(x)-1}{x-1}\right)=f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x)+o(\ln(x)) \\
\implies& \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\ln\left(\frac{f_{n}(x)-1}{x-1}\right)=\frac{f_{n-2}(x)\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x-1}}+o\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x-1}}\right)\xrightarrow{x\to 1} 0 \\
\implies& \lim_{x\to 1}\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\ln\left(\frac{f_{n}(x)-1}{x-1}\right)\right)=1
\end{align*}
Hence :
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x^{x^{x{^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}-1}{x-1}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}}=1
$$

*Indeed a fascinating problem and once more thanks for Claude and Ninad for your help*

Comment: It is a nice answer that I upvoted. The problem is that I do not think that you could go beyond the limit itself (if you have time to waste, have a look at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/teaching-limits-and-asymptotics-at-the-same-time )

Comment: Thank you very much sir!